# PreparedStatement setNull(..)

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Java PreparedStatement provides a possibility to explicitely set a Null value. This possibility is:

```
prepStmt.setNull(parameterIndex, Types.VARCHAR);
```

Are the semantics of this call the same as when using a specific setType with a null parameter?

```
prepStmt.setString(null);
```

?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/preparedstatement.html) says:

> ##### 6.1.5 Sending JDBC NULL as an IN parameter
>
> The `setNull` method allows a programmer to send a JDBC `NULL` (a generic SQL `NULL`) value to the database as an IN parameter. Note, however, that one must still specify the JDBC type of the parameter.
>
> A JDBC `NULL` will also be sent to the database when a Java `null` value is passed to a `setXXX` method (if it takes Java objects as arguments). The method `setObject`, however, can take a `null` value only if the JDBC type is specified.

So yes they're equivalent.

Comment: +1: Interesting.  I assumed that's how setXXX worked with nulls, but I'd never actually tested it or read the docs for it.

Comment: I don't suppose there is something like myPreparedStatement.setInteger(myIntegerObject) (although I see that exact method name does not exist) in the case I'm wanting use a potentially null integer?  Otherwise I'm going to have to use an if/else statement, calling .setInt() one way and .setNull() the other way, which seems a bit tedious.

Comment: @ardave, yes that's what I mean by my final paragraph

Comment: @user74754 if you aren't sure whether your Integer is going to be null, and you don't want to use an if/else, then you could do this: stmt.setObject(1, myPossiblyNullInteger, java.sql.Types.INTEGER)

Answer (score 84):

but watch out for this....

```
Long nullLong = null;

preparedStatement.setLong( nullLong );
```

-thows null pointer exception-

because the protype is

```
setLong( long )
```

NOT

```
setLong( Long )
```

nice one to catch you out eh.

Comment: That is actually the example that brought me here.

Comment: In this case (using a Postgres DB in my case), you can use the setObject method.
`Long nullLong = null; preparedStatement.setObject(nullLong);`

Comment: @Owen : if(obj== null || obj == 0) {ps.setLong(INDEX_TWO, Types.BIGINT);} else {ps.setLong(INDEX_TWO, obj);}  worked for me

Comment: @casperw - according to the JDBC specification, not all database implementations will be able to handle passing a null to `setObject`.  If it works with the particular database implementations you are using, then that is fine, I suppose, but be aware that you do sacrifice some portability by doing so.

Answer (score 13):

Finally I did a small test and while I was programming it it came to my mind, that without the setNull(..) method there would be no way to set null values for the Java primitives. For Objects both ways

```
setNull(..)
```

and

```
set<ClassName>(.., null))
```

behave the same way.

Answer (score 13):

```
preparedStatement.setNull(index, java.sql.Types.NULL);
```

that should work for any type.
Though in some cases failure happens on the server-side, like:
for SQL:

```
COALESCE(?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Oracle 18XE fails with the wrong type: expected DATE, got STRING -- that is a perfectly valid failure;

Bottom line: it is good to know the type if you call `.setNull()`.

Answer (score 11):

You could also consider using `preparedStatement.setObject(index,value,type);`