# Uses of PreparedStatement setNull

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

What is the uses of setNull() method in PreparedStatement interface? I looked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357429/preparedstatement-setnull) post.

It says: `Without the setNull(..) method there would be no way to set null values for the Java primitives.`

however with autoboxing in JDK5, I think null values can be set on even primitive types.

There is another [post](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2004-09/msg00210.php) in some other forum says:`If you want to be portable to different databases, use the setNull() method.`

However there is nothing clearly mentioned in Java doc. Could you help me understanding this?

Comment: "however with autoboxing in JDK5, I think null values can be set on even primitive types." - wrong. Autoboxing means you can assign primitive values to variables of object type; it doesn't let you pass null to a method which takes a primitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easier to understand this if you view it from the database end. If you want to set a field to NULL in your database insert statement, then you need a way of telling the database that is should be set to NULL rather than the default value for the column. If in the database schema you have a nullable integer field, you would use set null to set it to the DB NULL value, rather than to its default value ( 0 ).

Comment: Yes.. this clears things. So, if you've to set something NULL, use setNull.

Comment: That's the way I understand it.