# JDBC what's the purpose of PreparedStatement#setNull

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I did an experiment with a table having a VARCHAR column with null values trying to get the number of rows that have a specific column NULL. I used three forms:

**form A**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM buyers WHERE buye_resp IS NULL
```

**form B**

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM buyers WHERE buye_resp = ?
```

... where the parameter is provided with **setString(1, null)**

**form C**

... like **form B** but the parameter is set with **setNull(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR)**

Of the three forms, only **form A** produced the correct result, forms B and C both returned 0 (code of the three forms at the end of the post). Which begs the question: what's the purpose of **setNull**?

The tests where run against a PostgreSQL 9.2 database.

### code

```
private static int numOfRows_formA(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    ResultSet         rs   = null;
    try {
        String pstmStr = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM buyers WHERE buye_resp IS NULL";
        pstm = conn.prepareStatement(pstmStr);
        rs =  pstm.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        return rs.getInt(1);
    } finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(null, pstm, rs);
    }
}

private static int numOfRows_formB(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    ResultSet         rs   = null;
    try {
        String pstmStr = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM buyers WHERE buye_resp = ?";
        pstm = conn.prepareStatement(pstmStr);
        pstm.setString(1, null);
        rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        return rs.getInt(1);
    } finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(null, pstm, rs);
    }
}

private static int numOfRows_formC(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    ResultSet         rs   = null;
    try {
        String pstmStr = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM buyers WHERE buye_resp = ?";
        pstm = conn.prepareStatement(pstmStr);
        pstm.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        return rs.getInt(1);
    } finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(null, pstm, rs);
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357429/preparedstatement-setnull

Comment: Been there before asking. Not quite the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL uses [ternary logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), therefore `buye_responsible = ?` always returns `unknown` (and never `true`) when `buye_responsible` is `null`. That's why you need `IS NULL` to check for `null`.

`setNull()` can be used, for example, when you need to pass `null`s to `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements. Since methods such as `setInt()` and `setLong()` take primitive types (`int`, `long`) you need a special method to pass `null` in this case.

Comment: so, if I get this right, setNull is mainly - if not exclusively - for INSERT / UPDATE statements and likely a code smell in FIND statements.

Answer (score 1):

In data base system a null is not equal to another null so 
the line `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vat_refund.er_buyers WHERE buye_responsible = null` won't return any record. The setNull() method simply set a null at the index position.`Sets the designated parameter to SQL NULL.` This from the JAVA API. That is it will set a SQL null for that index, but it don't use isNull() function as desired by you.
So that is why for form C also you are not getting any result.