# What to expect with PreparedStatement::setInt null input

Tags: java, prepared-statement, autoboxing

According to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357429/preparedstatement-setnull), this code:

```
try(PreparedStatement p_stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    p_stmt.setString(1, null);
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
try(PreparedStatement p_stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    p_stmt.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    ...
}
```

My question is, is this the same with `int` / `Integer` ?? In other words, what would this code do:

```
try(PreparedStatement p_stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    Integer i = null;
    p_stmt.setInt(1, i);
    ...
}
```

`setInt()` takes in a primitive `int` which cannot be null, but the unboxed `Integer` can be null.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9542866/207421) in your own link answers this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line

```
p_stmt.setInt(1, i);
```

is compiled to

```
p_stmt.setInt(1, i.intValue());
```

Since `i` is referencing `null`, you will get a `NullPointerException`.

This is explained in more detail in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8).

> At run time, unboxing conversion proceeds as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - If `r` is a reference of type `Integer`, then unboxing conversion converts `r` into `r.intValue()`
> - If `r` is `null`, unboxing conversion throws a `NullPointerException`