# SQL error while updating a row

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, mysql-error-1064

Details of table under consideration :

[image]

Code used for updating rows is :

```
 public void updateEmployeeDetails(Employee employee) {

    Connection conn = JDBCUtility.getConnection();

    try {
        String updateSql = "UPDATE EMPLOYEE_INFO SET emp_name=?, location=?, email=?, dob=? WHERE emp_id=?";

        PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement(updateSql);
        ps.setString(1, employee.getEmp_name()); /*all the attributes of employee object are of type String */
        ps.setString(2, employee.getLocation());
        ps.setString(3, employee.getEmail());
        ps.setString(4, employee.getDob());
        ps.setString(5, employee.getEmp_id());
        ps.executeUpdate(updateSql);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Error Received :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, location=?, email=?, dob=? WHERE  emp_id=?' at line 1
```

Can anyone point out the error because I doubly checked any possible error in my query string? Is `varchar(45)` of mysql compatible with Java's `String`? i.e.      could `ps.setString(column_index, String)` be the root cause of error?

**DEBUG 1 :**

Considering `null` possibility I tried(in vain) following :

```
//  ps.setString(1, employee.getEmp_name());
//  ps.setString(2, employee.getLocation());
//  ps.setString(3, employee.getEmail());
//  ps.setString(4, employee.getDob());
//  ps.setString(5, employee.getEmp_id());

ps.setString(1, "Superman");
ps.setString(2, "Sky");
ps.setString(3, "anymail@dooodle.com");
ps.setString(4, "1-1-0111");
ps.setString(5, "501");
ps.executeUpdate(updateSql);
```

but still the same output is shown .

Comment: maybe some string is `null` and this post is relevant for this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357449/2186023

Comment: @DrCopyPaste see the debug info in my question

Answer (score 0):

What I would usually do is:

```
private static final String UPDATE_ITEM =
        "UPDATE `EMPLOYEE_INFO` SET emp_name=?, location=?, email=?, dob=? WHERE emp_id=?";

public void updateEmployeeDetails(Employee employee) {

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {

        conn = JDBCUtility.getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(UPDATE_ITEM);
        ps.setString(1, employee.getEmp_name()); /*all the attributes of employee object are of type String */
        ps.setString(2, employee.getLocation());
        ps.setString(3, employee.getEmail());
        ps.setString(4, employee.getDob());
        ps.setString(5, employee.getEmp_id());
        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But can you double check what this returns `employee.getEmp_name()`?

Comment: I did `System.out.println(employee.getEmp_name()+employee.getDob());` and it result was not `null` . It gave what I entered in the form. so no error in that/

Comment: @KNU did you try my answer?

Comment: Also reshuffling statements as suggested by you shouldn't be helpful as I have other function for other queries in exactly same fashion (in same class) which runs fine

Comment: @KNU there are actually a few changes but alright. :)

Answer (score 0):

After line by line verification I found error in following line :

```
ps.executeUpdate(updateSql);
```

**Conclusion**: the [`executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) was required in this case without passing any argument
Official Documentation :

```
int executeUpdate() throws SQLException

Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

Returns:
either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing
```