# java insert null but not primitive default value

Tags: java, jdbc

I want insert a null value into database instead of inserting default primitive value.

I have a class

```
class Test
(
    private int first;
    private int second;
    public Test() {}  
    public void setFirst(int val) {first = val;}
    public void setSecond(int val) {second = val;}
    public int getFirst() {return first;}
    public int getSecond() {return second;}
)
```

I have some code that initialize Test class:

Test my = new Test();
my.setFirst(100);

so we have now:
first = 100;
second = 0; -- since I don't initialize it and it default to zero "0" for int.

Now I insert the data into database table Test ...

```
Create table Test
(
  first number,
  second number
)
```

Java call ...

```
Test my = new Test();
my.setFirst(100);
String sql = "INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(?,?)";
PrepareStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, my.getFirst());    // will insert 100
ps.setInt(2, my.getSecond());   // will insert 0
```

I want insert NULL into "second" field since Test.second is not set in my code. I use the following trick:

```
class Test
(
    private int first = -999;
    private int second = -999;
    public Test() {}  
    public void setFirst(int val) {first = val;}
    public void setSecond(int val) {second = val;}
    public int getFirst() {return first;}
    public int getSecond() {return second;}
)


Test my = new Test();
my.setFirst(100);
String sql = "INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(?,?)";
PrepareStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

if (my.getFirst() == -999)
   ps.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER) // will insert NULL
else
   ps.setInt(1, my.getFirst());    // will insert 100


if (my.getSecond() == -999)
   ps.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER) // will insert NULL
else
   ps.setInt(2, my.getSecond());    // will insert 0
```

Does somebody has the best/nice solution to implement that ?

I get NullPointerException when use Integer, this is right since var is not initialized or I missed something here:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at UserQuiz.getFrom_flags_challenge_nid(UserQuiz:113)

UserQuiz. java
...
private Integer from_flags_challenge_nid;
public int getFrom_flags_challenge_nid() {
    return from_flags_challenge_nid;
}

public void setFrom_flags_challenge_nid(int from_flags_challenge_nid) {
    this.from_flags_challenge_nid = from_flags_challenge_nid;
}
...
```

Comment: You could use Integer instead of int, possibly.

Comment: Integer get me NullPointerException

Comment: Where is the NullPointerException when using Integer, can you copy/paste the stack-trace in this case?

Comment: It will throw an exception on `ps.setInt`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9542866/203117 for a similar question where this is explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `int` to `Integer` (everywhere - the field, parameter of setter and return type of getter) and then you can just try this:

```
ps.setObject(1, my.getFirst()/*may return null*/, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
ps.setObject(2, my.getSecond()/*may return null*/, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

Note that code like this:

```
private Integer from_flags_challenge_nid;
public int getFrom_flags_challenge_nid() {
   return from_flags_challenge_nid;
}
```

will throw a NullPointerException if `from_flags_challenge_nid` contains `null`.

Comment: got it.... so if changing Integer in getter and setter and variable from int to Integer, still get NullPointerException. this work fine for me: ps.setObject(2, my.getSecond()/*may return null*/, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

Comment: did you change the **return type**? the Exception must have an understandable reason...

Comment: yes,  public Integer getFrom_flags_challenge_nid() {
  return from_flags_challenge_nid;
 }. So now the question why ps.setInt(7,userquiz.getFrom_flags_challenge_nid()); failed when it return NULL and setObject work

Comment: ps.setInt(int, **int**) takes an **int** as value argument....by unboxing Integer (null) to int, you will get an NULLPOINTER

Comment: yes, i guess this a reason try convert Integer(null) to int +1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add this kind of behavior, why not extend `PreparedStatement` and provide your own implementation?

```
class MyPreparedStatement extends PreparedStatement {

    public void setNullableInt(int parameterIndex, int x)
        throws SQLException
        if (x == 0) {
            setNull(parameterIndex, java.sql.Types.INTEGER)
        }
        else {
            setInt(parameterIndex, x);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem with this is that `0` is not logically equivalent to `null`, and really shouldn't be treated as such. A common method if you're dealing with positive integers in general is to use something like `-1` to represent a 'non-value'.

Comment: not sure if that work since int is not null, default is 0. so my getSecond will return 0 and not null, according that logic it call setInt, instead of setNull

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer as it shouldn't have been checking for null.

Comment: hm ... see zero "0" can be a good int value, so zero is not NULL.

Comment: I agree. But you're initializing `second` to 0 and then trying to treat that as null already. Really if you want to use primitive integers, there is *no such thing as null*.

Comment: i guess can change: public void setNullableInt(int parameterIndex, Integer  x) and check if (x == null) the setNull